# Does editing file on ext4 creates additional copies?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Let's say I have file X with string ABCD. I then edit the file using open X, seek to 0, truncate, write 1234. Will ABCD remain anywhere on the harddrive? Assuming it would be large file over number of sectors / inodes.

Comment: Do you mean 'does ext4' do copy on write?

Comment: I am wondering if when large file is truncated, when I try to overwrite it from zero after truncating, the same sectors will be overwritten.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, there is no guarantee that if you truncate the file, you would get allocated the same block for the next write operation. In that case, you would indeed end up with a copy of the data in an old block.

If you are on an SSD, this is guaranteed to happen even if you overwrite the data byte-wise and regardless of the file system, as SSDs are always copy-on-write for performance reasons.

Comment: But the previous block has to be released which means zeroed or swapped with another block. SSD doesn't know the filesystem and the only tip it has are the zeroed (trimmed) blocks so it cant keep old copies on them because that would cripple wear levelling and degrade performance a lot. Zeroed block can be used in filesystem so it cannot intruduce data to it like copy of different file.

Comment: If you trim a block in the OS, you essentially tell the storage controller on the disk that you you don't need the block anymore and it may zero it. There is no guarantee when this will happen, it's an automatic background operation  that happens when the controller has time for it. Until that time, the data is still present on the disk.

Answer (score -1):

No, it does not. Also, file locking is used to prevent this, but that is up to the program’s developer.